# This function is currently applied to just one page, but is it possible to apply it to the entire spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is for google sheets. This function is currently applied to just one page, but is it possible to apply it to the entire spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Code should be added as text, not as image. Also add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hello @realitybug! Would you mind sharing the sheet you are using and eventually more information about the code snippet you provided? That would be of great help! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you're defining `sheet`. Right now, your code is specifying "DS1" only. The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) will return the range that was edited, so use that to determine the edited sheet.

```
var sheet = event.range.getSheet();
```

Comment: hmm okay so i tried replacing

var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('JohnDoe');

with 

var sheet = event.range.getSheet('DS1(v1));

but it didn't seem to work. im a little new to google sheet scripting editng so im not sure what to look for exactly.

the title of my spread sheet is 'DS1(v1)'

Comment: @realitybug Don't put anything in the parentheses. Use exactly what I wrote.